# Rails parameter injecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

Creating an authentication map of resources and roles in a management system.

My question is is it dependable to use the rails internal parameter variables?

e.g
`/invoices` goes to the `invoices` controller and yields `params[:controller] = "invoices"` and I have a filter:

```
def _can_i_access
  if user.can_access(params[:controller])
    ...
end
```

Is there a way for an attack to forge that params[:controller] variable and bypass my filter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as params are set on the client (view) side.  You should be using a variable at the model level to check if a user can access something.  For instance, in your users model have an access level variable that contains different levels of access is just one way to achieve this. Then in the controller you would do something like:

`def _can_i_access
  if user.access_level == <a certain level>
    ...
end`

Answer (score 0):

You can't really depend upon passed params, but there are far more reliable ways. Simply use the `controller_name` method in your action to get the name of the controller that was called.